# Excel Function to Access Function

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I created UPC check-digit function in excel which is working perfectly fine but i am now in need of creating same thing in MS Access.

here is the code:

```
Public Function CHECKDIGIT(UPC As String) As String

    If Len(UPC) = 8 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1)), -1) - (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1)))

    ElseIf Len(UPC) = 12 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1)), -1) - (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1)))

    ElseIf Len(UPC) = 13 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1)) + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1)) * 3, -1) - (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1)) + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1)) * 3)

    ElseIf Len(UPC) = 14 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1), Mid(UPC, 13, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1)), -1) - (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1), Mid(UPC, 13, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1)))

    ElseIf Len(UPC) = 17 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1), Mid(UPC, 13, 1), Mid(UPC, 15, 1)) + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1), Mid(UPC, 14, 1), Mid(UPC, 16, 1)) * 3, -1) - (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1), Mid(UPC, 13, 1), Mid(UPC, 15, 1)) + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1), Mid(UPC, 14, 1), Mid(UPC, 16, 1)) * 3)

    ElseIf Len(UPC) = 18 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1), Mid(UPC, 13, 1), Mid(UPC, 15, 1), Mid(UPC, 17, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1), Mid(UPC, 14, 1), Mid(UPC, 16, 1)), -1) - (WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 1, 1), Mid(UPC, 3, 1), Mid(UPC, 5, 1), Mid(UPC, 7, 1), Mid(UPC, 9, 1), Mid(UPC, 11, 1), Mid(UPC, 13, 1), Mid(UPC, 15, 1), Mid(UPC, 17, 1)) * 3 + WorksheetFunction.Sum(Mid(UPC, 2, 1), Mid(UPC, 4, 1), Mid(UPC, 6, 1), Mid(UPC, 8, 1), Mid(UPC, 10, 1), Mid(UPC, 12, 1), Mid(UPC, 14, 1), Mid(UPC, 16, 1)))

    ElseIf Len(UPC) <> 8 Or Len(UPC) <> 12 Or Len(UPC) <> 13 Or Len(UPC) <> 14 Or Len(UPC) <> 17 Or Len(UPC) <> 18 Then

        CHECKDIGIT = "MISSING DIGITS"

    End If
End Function
```

Is there any easy way to convert this to MS Access?
To my knowledge not all formulas will transfer directly to access so I image I will need to build custom function in Access too.

Any idea how to go with this?

Thanks, 
Slav

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Sum(x, y)` = `x + y`, and `WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(x)` = `Round(x + 0.5)`. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work equally well in Excel and Access:

```
Public Function CHECKDIGIT(UPC As String) As String
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Select Case Len(UPC)
        Case 8, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18
            n = 0
            For i = 1 To Len(UPC) - 1
                If ((Len(UPC) - i) Mod 2) = 1 Then
                    n = n + CInt(Mid(UPC, i, 1)) * 3
                Else
                    n = n + CInt(Mid(UPC, i, 1))
                End If
            Next
            CHECKDIGIT = CStr(Int(n / 10 + 0.99) * 10 - n)

        Case Else

            CHECKDIGIT = "MISSING DIGITS"

    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Ok perfect. This one is working like a charm. Can i use this as an function in Access? Like in excel i would just type =CHECKDIGIT(A1) but in access i know it will be different. Should i see this as part of built in function in Access?

Comment: I figured it out. I just call it within query or a form. YowE3K .....man you rock. this is awesome.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Slavisha - `man you rock` - hmm, usually when people refer to both me and rocks in the same sentence it is with the expression "YowE3K has rocks in his head".

Comment: No :-) in my case you actually saved me so much effort. If you are ever in Atlanta... you have a drink on me. 

Now im going to study your logic. I have bit hard time understanding what exactly you did there line by line. it gives same  results as my function but your is way more elegant.

Comment: Mine is just looking at each character (except the last, checkdigit, character), deciding whether it is an even or odd position, and then deciding therefore whether to multiply by 1 or 3.  The sum of those can then be deducted from the next higher multiple of 10 to get the checkdigit.  (Actually, I just realised that the last step could be `CHECKDIGIT = CStr((1000 - n) Mod 10)` instead of `CHECKDIGIT = CStr(Int(n / 10 + 0.99) * 10 - n)` - that might be simpler.)

Comment: @Slavisha - Unfortunately Atlanta is too far from Sydney, so I don't think I will be able to collect on that drink.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the code YowE3K.  I think there is something missing in that code. When i run it against results i get using my code It fails.

```
UPC CHCKDIGIT   NEW CHKDIGIT
018371009355    5   5
00018371009355  5   5
7501206634004   4   10
00018371019354  4   14
018371019354    4   14
```

Also by using function i just found out that i cant use the function as part of data entry validation. I will have to use formula using what Comintern suggested above.

Thank you both guys for helping with this.

Comment: I see I had two errors in my code - (a) I hadn't noticed the difference in the function between even and odd length UPC codes, and (b) I should have been using an `Int` instead of a `Round`.  I fixed both errors in my answer, just in case anyone else needs a UPC checkcode function in the future.